# Contravariance in Action lambda - C#

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, variance

I have a class hierarchy like this

```
public abstract class CalendarEventBase{}

public class TrainingEvent : CalendarEventBase{}

public class AuditEvent : CalendarEventBase{}
```

I wanted to create an action Action lamda that had a generic type paramater of type CalendarEventBase that I could assign to the following different methods:

```
public void EmailCancelation(TrainingEvent trainingEvent)

public void EmailCancelation(AuditEvent auditEvent)
```

I created the following illegal assignment:

```
Action<CalendarEventBase> emailCancelation = _trainingService.EmailTrainingCancellation;
```

The compiler complains that it was expecting a method with void(CalendarEventBase) as a signature.  I was surprised by this as I thought it would accept a more derived type.

To get round this, I created the following delegate that allows me to complete my task:

```
public delegate void EmailCancelation<in T>(T calendarEvent) where T : CalendarEventBase;
```

My question is, could I have completed the task without having to create an additional delegate?  I thought I could just create an Action instance.

Any help or pointers, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line:

```
Action<CalendarEventBase> emailCancelation = _trainingService.EmailTrainingCancellation;
```

is actually expecting *covariance*, not *contravariance*.  But that logically doesn't make sense; the method expects a `TrainingEvent` as input - how can you pass a *more general* type (`CalendarEventBase`) to it?

This isn't legal:

```
// What if the method wants to make the lion roar but you pass in a goat?
Action<Mammal> mammalAction = MethodThatTakesALion;
```

but this is fine:

```
// Anything that you want to with an animal, you can do with a mammal.
Action<Mammal> mammalAction = MethodThatTakesAnAnimal;
```

Answer (score 1):

The lambda can't support this, because the emailCancelation variable you've declared will accept a CalendarEventBase, but the actual implementation will only accept the TrainingEvent. What would happen if someone were to call emailCancelation with an AuditEvent parameter?